# How do you redirect a non-logged in user from a specific page in drupal?

Tags: drupal-7

I want to have 2 pages, one will exist for all users but if you are logged in it redirects you to another page.

Answer (score 0):

Write a module and use the [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7) function like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 */
function MODULENAME_init() {
  if (user_is_logged_in()) {
    drupal_goto('path_to_other_page');
  }
}
```

This hooks is only intended to be called for non-cached pages, so hook_init() is the hook I would use for what you are wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the very popular [LoginToboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan/) module. Among other things, it allows you to set a page where the user is redirected after logging in.